# Insert a blank line afer a specific key word in a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file containing lines

```
0.00  600.00  2214.28   785.71 1.00000 SEDS1-BOTTOM
0.00  600.00  2214.28   785.71 1.00000 SEDS1-TOP
0.00  600.00  1500.00     0.00 1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM
0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
0.00  600.00  2218.64   790.51 1.00000 SEDS1-BOTTOM
0.00  600.00  2218.64   790.51 1.00000 SEDS1-TOP
0.00    0.00  600.00  1500.00  1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM
0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
0.00  600.00  1500.00     0.00 1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM
0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
```

My output file should have Blant row after  WATER-BOTTOM like given below

```
0.00  600.00  2214.28   785.71 1.00000 SEDS1-BOTTOM
0.00  600.00  2214.28   785.71 1.00000 SEDS1-TOP
0.00  600.00  1500.00     0.00 1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM

0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
0.00  600.00  2218.64   790.51 1.00000 SEDS1-BOTTOM
0.00  600.00  2218.64   790.51 1.00000 SEDS1-TOP
0.00    0.00  600.00  1500.00  1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM

0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
0.00  600.00  1500.00     0.00 1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM

0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, it's cleanest with awk:

```
awk '{print} $NF ~ /WATER-BOTTOM/{print ""}' input
```

or

```
awk '{printf "%s\n%s", $0, $NF ~ /WATER-BOTTOM/ ? "\n" : ""}' input
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '1;/WATER-BOTTOM/{print ""}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

`1`: `1` is making condition true for `awk` and it is printing lines here(all lines of Input_file).

`;/WATER-BOTTOM/`: `;` segregating `1` from `/WATER-BOTTOM/`. `/WATER-BOTTOM/` means checking condition if a line contains string then do action mentioned inside `{...}` following it.

`{print ""}`: Printing NULL value here which will cause a new line to be printed whenever a line contains string `WATER-BOTTOM`.

Answer (score 1):

Crude but effective:

```
cat myfile | sed 's/WATER-BOTTOM/WATER-BOTTOM\n/' > myfile
```

Comment: @rehman it’s replacing `WATER-BOTTOM` with `WATER-BOTTOM` plus a new line character.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative sed command might be sed with using append feature.

```
cat test.txt | sed '/WATER-BOTTOM$/a'
```

'i' instead of 'a' would insert blank rows above instead below.

For second answer by Bohemian, *WATER-BOTTOM* in the replacement place can be skipped by using the '***&***' symbol instead:

```
cat myfile | sed 's/WATER-BOTTOM$/&\n/'
```

Comment: getting Error $sed: -e expression #1, char 12: expected \ after `a', `c' or `i'

Comment: Might be dependent on version of sed. Does cat test.txt | sed '/WATER-BOTTOM$/a""', or cat test.txt | sed '/WATER-BOTTOM$/a\' gives you error as well?